# MySQL: will auto_incremented rows inserted in batch always have adjacent ids?

Tags: mysql

When 2 queries start at the same time and insert multiple rows, is it guaranteed that the ids will be adjacent? For example query 1 inserts rows a,b,c query 2 - rows c,d,e. Query 1 finishes and reports insertId of 1, will it always mean that row a was inserted with id 1, b - 2, c - 3, or it is possible that a has id 1, but c has id 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's true for InnoDB :

> When accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a special
>   table-level AUTO-INC lock that it keeps to the end of the current SQL
>   statement, not to the end of the transaction. The special lock release
>   strategy was introduced to improve concurrency for inserts into a
>   table containing an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Nevertheless, two
>   transactions cannot have the AUTO-INC lock on the same table
>   simultaneously, which can have a performance impact if the AUTO-INC
>   lock is held for a long time. That might be the case for a statement
>   such as INSERT INTO t1 ... SELECT ... FROM t2 that inserts all rows
>   from one table into another.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-traditional.html

Not sure about myisam

Comment: Since MyISAM only supports table locks instead of row locks, the DBMS will lock the whole table on insert. If there are two insert queries in parallel, one has to wait. Since the insertion is pretty linear then, the auto_increment values will be pretty linear too.